# Why when using Lerp and StartCoroutine to Lerp between -3 and 3 it's not working?

Tags: unity, c#

```
private bool alreadyFading = false;
```

Then

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Teleporting Object")
        {

            if (!alreadyFading) StartCoroutine(Teleport(-3, 3, 5f));
        }
    }
```

And

```
IEnumerator Teleport(float from, float to, float duration)
    {
        alreadyFading = true;

        var timePassed = 0f;
        while (timePassed < duration)
        {
            var factor = timePassed / duration;
            var value = Mathf.Lerp(from, to, factor);

            material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", value);

            yield return null;
        }

        material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", to);

        alreadyFading = false;
    }
```

Using a break point it's getting to the Teleport function but it's not changing the values from -3 to 3.
It does nothing to the shader to the property _DissolveAmount.

I want it to change the value from -3 to 3 with duration once not ping pong. but it's not just it's just don't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that you're not incrementing the variable `timePassed` so the Coroutine is stuck infinitely in the while loop.

As for the `yield return null`[I think it's best explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41720468) but basically once a coroutine has yielded, the Main Thread continues running. On the next frame, Unity will find stacked coroutine and will call them from where they left off at the yield.

I suggest you change it to this (didn't test the code but it should hopefully work)

```
IEnumerator Teleport(float from, float to, float duration)
    {
        alreadyFading = true;

        var timePassed = 0f;
        while (timePassed < duration)
        {
            var factor = timePassed / duration;
            var value = Mathf.Lerp(from, to, factor);

            material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", value);
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", to);

        alreadyFading = false;
    }
```

`Time.deltaTime` is the amount of seconds it took for the engine to process the previous frame